# Why the grid view is not being displayed on the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have just started working on `ASP.NET` *web forms* and i have created a `GridView` which is just for now a plain `GridView`. 
But when i run the page it is displayed at the browser.

My Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderColor="#FF99CC" BorderStyle="Solid">
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date of Birth" HeaderText="Date of Birth" SortExpression="Date of Birth" />                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nationality" HeaderText="Nationality" SortExpression="Nationality" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" SortExpression="Mobile" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="Course" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Greaduation Year" HeaderText="Greaduation Year" SortExpression="Greaduation Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Major" HeaderText="Major" SortExpression="Major" />                
    </columns>                        
</asp:GridView>
```

Do i need a data source for gridview?

Comment: obviously you have to set the datasource so that gridview can show binded items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Gender", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Email", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("DateofBirth", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Nationality", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Mobile", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Course", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("GreaduationYear", DbType.String);
dt.Columns.Add("Major", DbType.String);
```

Fill the data in `dt` from database, then bind:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Remove the space in `DataField="Date of Birth"` to `DataField="DateofBirth"`

Comment: + 1 Good point. `<asp:BoundField DataField="Date of Birth" HeaderText="Date of Birth" SortExpression="Date of Birth" />` Should instead be `<asp:BoundField DataField="DateofBirth" HeaderText="Date of Birth" SortExpression="DateofBirth" />`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to set the data source in code behind (aspx.cs). You can do it in `Page_Load` method like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var data = ... // code that retrieves the data here
        GridView1.DataSource = data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Please note that the code that retrieves the data depends on how you connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need a `DataSource` for your `GridView`. And if you'r not binding your GridView in *code behind*, then it that `GridView` does not have a `DataSource`. You can add the following  code

```
var objDataSource; // # This can be any collection or DataTable, any suitable type of your choosing

// # TODO : Generate your data into objDatasource

GridView1.DataSource = objDataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Make sure that field names in `objDataSource` matches `DataField` values of `BoundField`

You can also bind using

- ObjectDataSource
- XmlDataSource
- SqlDataSource

For more, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx)